# How can I Quick Look native cpp class using the visual debugger?

Tags: c++, ios, debugging, quicklook, xcode5.1

In correspondence with the following post:

[How can I Quick Look custom objects with Xcode 5 visual debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052666/how-can-i-quick-look-custom-objects-with-xcode-5-visual-debugger)

I would like to ask if it is possible to have a quick look for native cpp class objects ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I asked this question on Apple's developer's forum.
The answer is as follows:

*Custom Quick Look doesn't work for C++, right now*

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that I understand this right and you are talking about how to look at source code (.cpp) files using QuickLook, you may want to have a look at [the amazing QLStephen plugin](https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen/downloads) (It's really just called `QLStephen`, but it's amazing).
You can find some instructions [here](http://osxdaily.com/2013/01/30/preview-all-text-files-in-quick-look-with-the-qlstephen-plugin-for-os-x/).
You can also grab the [source](https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen), and do your own custom changes.

This gets even more awesome when you add the ability to select and copy text from Quicklook, using the following command in the terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder QLEnableTextSelection -boolean YES; 
killall Finder
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, however it is not what I was looking for. Take a look on my question and the post it relates to.