# Objective c - Get details with the debugger

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I try to get more details about objects from the debugger

I see this object:

```
 <UIImageView: 0x7febf0ebcd20; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7febf0ebce20>>
```

How can I know what `UIImageView` the debugger is pointing on?
How can I get more details about this object like the image itself,or if there is an image inside of it etc...?

Comment: The Xcode debugger has Quicklook build in. Touch the eye symbol next to the image view.

Comment: Yeah, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052666/how-can-i-quick-look-custom-objects-with-xcode-5-visual-debugger