# How do I get LLDB to output images?

Tags: c++, xcode, image, debugging, lldb

I have a single 8-bit channel buffer whose contents I would like to see in the middle of a debugging session. Using whatever might be available under Xcode/LLDB, can this be done? A solution that uses a separate window (or even dumping to an external file) is fine.

What changes about the answer if the image is 8-bit planar RGBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking about:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/CustomClassDisplay_in_QuickLook/Introduction/Introduction.html

This was answered here in:

[How can I Quick Look custom objects with Xcode 5 visual debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052666/how-can-i-quick-look-custom-objects-with-xcode-5-visual-debugger#21153058)

You have to be able to convert your image to a UIImage or some other type that the QuickLook system natively understands.